# Find all sublist of list in minimum time in python

Tags: python, list, loops, time, sublist

I have to find all sublist of list in a minimal time 
I have tried it but its taking very much time

```
X=[]
for i in range(len(N)+1):
    for j in range(len(N)+1):
        c=N[i:j]
        X.append(c)
X2 = [x for x in X if x != []]
```

Comment: You shouldn't create all these empty lists in the first time. "In minimum time" doesn't mean much, though...

Comment: Find all sublists of a list you mean power set?

Comment: means if input is [1,2,3,4] output should be [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `itertools` might be faster than using nested for loops.

### Code

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def sublist(ls):
    chain_obj = chain.from_iterable(combinations(ls, r) for r in range(1,len(ls)+1))
    for i in chain_obj:
        print(i)

ls=['1','2','3']
sublist(ls)
```

### Output

```
('1',)
('2',)
('3',)
('1', '2')
('1', '3')
('2', '3')
('1', '2', '3')
```

### EDIT 1

Hope this helps,

```
from itertools import combinations

def sublist(ls):
    res = [ls[x:y] for x, y in combinations( range(len(ls) + 1), r = 2)]
    print(res)

ls=['1','2','3','4']

print(sublist(ls))
```

### Output

```
[['1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['2'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '3', '4'], ['3'], ['3', '4'], ['4']]
```

Comment: in the output there is (1,3) also which should not be there because it is not sublist of it

Comment: i want output without it

Comment: if input is [1,2,3,4] otput should be [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]